# Socket function doesn’t recognize host name (Python)

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So. I’m trying to establish a simple IRC esque program. Send message to server, server receives messages and prints it. Simple. Well, the problem i’m having is the connection part. I do socket.gethostname() and it returns my device name. I plug it into the client, it says “(my device name) is not defined”. So, what do i change here? I can provide more details if asked.

Comment: try local host and see if it works i.e `127.0.0.7`.In server enter `host=127.0.0.7` and in host input enter the same

Comment: I’m running the server and client on two separate devices, so...

Comment: they both have to be on the same network then

Comment: I don’t currently have another device here, so what i meant by other device is a friend running the server

Comment: Yes but it will only be possible to connect if you both are on the same network as i said earlier

Comment: By that, do you mean connecting by local host or connecting in general? Sorry, i’m a bit new to networking.

Comment: what i mean is that the server and the client file both should be connected to the same network i.e same wifi / connection then its possible for connection using socket.gethostname()

Comment: Well, if we were on seperate networks, what hostnsme do i use?

Comment: or else i could provide you the code,and you can run both server and client on your system and check it out

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have knowledge for separate network

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`socket.gethostname()` is to get your own device's host name.
what you need for connection is your server's IP or host name.
Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) for more details.